# XSLT "Move" sibling content into closed preceding-sibling

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

My input has some non-conforming markup that I would like to fix, e.g.

```
<ul>
  <li>
  </li>
  <p>This is the first bullet item</p>
  <li>
  </li>
  <p>This is the second bullet item</p>
</ul>
...
<ul>
  <li>I am fine. No need to monkey with me.</li>
<ul>
```

which should be

```
<ul>
  <li>This is the first bullet item</li>
  <li>This is the second bullet item</li>
</ul>
...
<ul>
  <li>I am fine. No need to monkey with me.</li>
<ul>
```

I know how to "unwrap" the `p` elements

```
<xsl:template match="p[parent::ul and preceding-sibling::li]">
    <!-- Don't wrap or copy. Just process content. -->
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

but I can't figure out how to have the content of the unwrapped `p`s appear within the `li`s in the output. Somehow, I'm guessing, I need to identify the empty `li`s, instead create a new `li` and then add the content of the following-sibling `p`. Something like

```
<xsl:template match="li[not(li) and not(normalize-space())]">
    <li>
        <!-- how do I get content of following-sibling p here?? -->
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </li>
</xsl:template>
```

But this (obviously) does not work. I'm stuck and cannot find a solution. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Somehow, I'm guessing, I need to identify the empty lis, instead create a new li and then add the content of the following-sibling p.

This seems to be a good idea, so try this:

```
<xsl:template match="li[normalize-space(text())='']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::p[1]/text()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This fills empty `li` elements with the `text()` of the following `p` element.

To get rid of the `p` elements, (somewhat) invert the XPath expression and put it in an empty template:

```
<xsl:template match="p[normalize-space(preceding-sibling::li[1]/text())='']" />
```

**Output then is:**

```
<ul>
  <li>This is the first bullet item</li>
  <li>This is the second bullet item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This got me on the right track, but for some reason if I used `<xsl:copy>` as above resulting markup was `<li/>The text from the following sibling.`. `<li>` did not work either. Same result. It was only when I replaced `<xsl:copy>` with `<li class="whatever">` applying some attribute to the `<li>` that it actually appeared in the markup as expected. Odd.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="ul">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="li">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::p[1]" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:template match="ul">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="p">
            <li>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

---

### Added in response to edited question:

If this problem only affects some `ul` nodes, you can restrict the template by changing:

```
<xsl:template match="ul">
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="ul[p]">
```

or:

```
<xsl:template match="ul[li[not(normalize-space())]]">
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Some `<li>` tags are non-conforming -- containing only whitespace and followed by sibling `<p>` -- not all.

Comment: Please edit your question and show a more representative example.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: That's still ambiguous. Do you have two types of `ul` where each `li` follows the same pattern? Or can there be a mixture of both `li` types within the same `ul`?

Comment: The example is now representative of the input. Some `ul`s are OK, some have empty `li` followed by `p`. I have no control over input. Thanks.

Comment: See the addition to my answer.